# Use two different toolbars into KendoGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid

Is it possible to use two different toolbars in the same kendoGrid

I have:

```
 toolbar: ["excel"],
   //toolbar: kendo.template($("#template").html()
```

Is it possible to call these two at the same time and execute it?

Comment: No you can always only display one toolbar per control. But you can have multiple buttons if that is what you are after.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to combine a custom template with the pre-built export to excel button Kendo offers you, you can do it like this:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <!-- your custom toolbar buttons -->

        <!--Adding pre-built buttons-->
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-excel" href="#"><span class="k-icon k-i-excel"></span>Excel</a>
        <a class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-add"><span class="k-icon k-i-add"></span>Add New</a>
     </div>
</script>
```

Kendo knows that `k-grid-excel` and `k-grid-add` are supposed to be the export to excel and add buttons and renders them automatically.